# jquery datatables custom ajax client

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, customization

I have a custom javascript client that works with a remote API using ajax.

Suppose it to be MyApiClient like below:

```
var MyApiClient = function() {
   this.Invoke = function (config, callback) {
     // ...
   }
}
```

How can I configure jQuery Datatables so that I can use MyApiClient rather than the built-in ajax working that jQuery Datatables provides internally?

That is, suppose for loading your remote data, you need to call your client this way:

```
var client = new MyApiClient();

client.Invoke({ url: '/api/app/v1/some-entity/all', function(result, err) {
     // ...
  }
});
```

Thank you already

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option to define a function to retrieve the data through your own Ajax call.

> As a function, making the Ajax call is left up to yourself allowing complete control of the Ajax request. Indeed, if desired, a method other than Ajax could be used to obtain the required data, such as Web storage or a Firebase database.
>
> When the data has been obtained from the data source, the second parameter (`callback` here) should be called with a single parameter passed in - the data to use to draw the table.

For example:

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
     var client = new MyApiClient();
     client.Invoke({ url: '/api/app/v1/some-entity/all', function(result, err){

           // Pass the data to jQuery DataTables
           callback(result);

        }
     });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you.
This is not limited only to data retrieval. We need to customize other operations such as **insert, delete, update** and **pagination**.
Is it possible to use MyApiClient in these operations in a similar way as you said, in place of the internal workings of jQuery Datatables?